# Why apply filterbank in power sepstrum not log power spectrum for cepstral coefficients feature(MFCC, IMFCC, LFCC)

Tags: filters, mfcc

In the original method for MFCC and any other method based on cepstral coefficients
The original step is like this:
|FFT|^2 -> Filterbank -> Log -> DCT

but why not like that:
|FFT|^2 -> Log -> Filterbank -> DCT

I didn't find the first paper proposed MFCC, 
Could someone please share it with me? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The M in the [Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) stands for the [Mel scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale).

The Mel Scale accounts for a non-linear phenomenon associated with perception (in general) where equal input intervals **do not** produce proportionally equal perceptual intervals. For more information about this, you might want to check [this Q&A](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54367/what-does-mean-when-we-say-mel-scale-reflects-how-humans-hear-musical-tone/54374#54374) and its references.

The $\log$ function in this process is what "transforms" the input from Hz to the Mel scale.

There are quite a few fundamental references in the Wikipedia resources cited above, including a reference to [the paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale#cite_note-stevens1937-1) that established the Mel scale.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I am not sure which "vertical axis" you are referring to in the comments because if you are referring to the *"vertical axis" of the FFT* then the answer would be *"no"*, but if you are referring to the **"vertical axis" of a spectrogram** then the answer would be **"yes"** because **that axis** is the one that corresponds to **->frequency<-**.

With reference to the following image (which is reproduced from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale#/media/File:Mel-Hz_plot.svg) ), the Mel Scale is what creates this non-linear mapping. Therefore, you use the filterbank to segment your frequency domain into $N$ "bands" to then take the log of the power within those bands.

Hope this is more clear (?)

[image]

Comment: Thank you~Thanks for your share. But I still don't find the answer from them. Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I know that Mel-scale is used to like human perception, But I don't know why apply filter ( not only MFCC but also LFCC and other cepstral coefficients method) before log but not after log(|FFT|)? Because the logarithmic algorithm only affects the vertical axis, right? So, why we always apply it after log? Thank you ：）

Comment: @zlin Please see edits and also [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/help-calculating-understanding-the-mfccs-mel-frequency-cepstrum-coefficients)

Comment: Thank you again, : )  The share from you are so nice, but I still cannot found the answer that I want. I mean the "vertical axis" of the FFT, (1)after FFT, we get spectrum in the frequency domain and the vertical axis is linear. (2)then we apply filterbank in |FFT| (sometime |FFT|^2)  (3) then we apply log in the results from step (2), the vertical axis turns to log, right? So I want to know, why we apply filter in the FFT but not log|FFT|? The filter need log too? Do I miss something?